# estou tendo problemas ao carrega bootstrap-vue js

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, vue.js

```
import Vue from 'vue' 
import App from './App.vue'
import BootstrapVue from 'bootstrap-vue' 
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
import 'bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-      
vue.css'
 Vue.use(BootstrapVue);
 new Vue({ el: '#app',
 render: h => h(App) })
```

> ERROR in ./~/bootstrap-vue/dist/bootstrap-vue.css Module parse failed:
>   C:\Users\Batip\Desktop\projeto-teste\myproject\node_modules\bootstrap-vue\dist\bootstrap-vue.css 
>   Unexpected token (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle
>   this file type.

Comment: Tens o style loader nos loaders do webpack? `{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
   },`

Comment: Olá marcelo, eu recomendaria utilizar o bootstrap através do CDN mesmo a build fica mais leve e o site mais rápido

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Junta no `webpack.config.js` o loader respectivo, juntamente com o que já deves ter para compilar os ficheiros `.vue`:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/,
    loader: 'vue-loader'
},
{
    test: /\.css$/,
    loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
},
```

Isso implica que deves ter o `css-loader` e o `vue-loader` no package.json, instalados.

Comment: valeu mesmo sergio